# Is my question better for Unix or this place?

Tags: support

I wonder how a Linux system can comply with "payment card industry security standard" https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard

For instance if there is a specific distribution that complies "out of the box".

Would that question be alright here or is it better to ask it on the Unix Q&A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question would be more suited on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Don't forget to add the `distribution-choice` tag to your question, as this tag is specifically made to gather such kind of questions.

At the opposite, product recommendations are considered off-topic here, on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).